# How do you name a something as approximately equal?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Let's say I following have code:

```
private bool ErrorLogExists(LogEvent logEvent, DateTime filterStart)
{
    var startTimeFrom = logEvent.StartTime.TruncateMilliseconds();
    var startTimeTo = startTimeFrom.AddSeconds(1);

    return _existingErrorLogs.Any(x =>
        x.Name == logEvent.Name &&
        x.EventDateTime >= filterStart &&
        x.EventDateTime >= startTimeFrom &&
        x.EventDateTime <= startTimeTo);
}
```

The problem is that I think it is terrible.

---

I might just rename `startTimeFrom` and `startTimeTo` and remove :

```
x.EventDateTime >= filterStart &&
```

as a cached view is already returned and it is no longer needed there.

---

I am tempted to write :

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    internal const double AcceptableTolerance = .0005;
    public static bool IsApproximately(this double thisValue, double thatValue, double tolerance = AcceptableTolerance)
    {
        return Math.Abs(thisValue - thatValue) <= tolerance;
    }
}
public static class DatetimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsApproximately(this DateTime thisTime, DateTime thatTime, double toleranceInSeconds = DoubleExtensions.AcceptableTolerance)
    {
        var thisTimeInSeconds = thisTime.AsTotalSeconds();
        var thatTimeInSeconds = thatTime.AsTotalSeconds();

        return thisTimeInSeconds.IsApproximately(thatTimeInSeconds, toleranceInSeconds);
    }

    public static double AsTotalSeconds(this DateTime thisTime)
    {
        return (thisTime - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

so I could instead use

```
private bool ErrorLogExists(LogEvent logEvent, DateTime filterStart)
{
    return _existingErrorLogs.Any(x =>
        x.Name == logEvent.Name &&
        x.EventDateTime.IsApproximately(logEvent.StartTime));
}
```

---

Reason why I would leave AsTotalSeconds as public, is that I would use it in tests. As in test tests, I already seem to have this partly supported. If I assume that I have:

```
var thisTimeInSeconds = thisTime.AsTotalSeconds();
var thatTimeInSeconds = thatTime.AsTotalSeconds();
var acceptableTolerance = .0005;
```

I could write :

```
Assert.That(thisTimeInSeconds, Is.EqualTo(thatTimeInSeconds).Within(acceptableTolerance);
thisTimeInSeconds.Should().BeApproximately(thatTimeInSeconds, acceptableTolerance);
```

---

The problem that I am facing is that

```
x.EventDateTime.IsApproximately(logEvent.StartTime))
```

has arguably even worse readability. People doing my code review might say :

- "WTF is this?" / "WTF is that?" (I admit, I picked names so I could say that)
- Why do we need IsApproximately?
- Why is that an extension method and not a class method?
- Is that DateTimes responsibility to know about this?
- Is the logic change necessary?
- Fine, you have DateTimeExtensions, why do you need DoubleExtensions?

---

My question is: How would you refactor this code?

---

### Edit:

What I have currently:

```
    private bool ErrorLogExists(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        var errorLogToleranceInMilliseconds = Properties.Settings.Default.ErrorLogToleranceInMilliseconds;
        var eventDateTimeFrom = logEvent.StartTime.AddMilliseconds(-errorLogToleranceInMilliseconds);
        var eventDateTimeTo = logEvent.StartTime.AddMilliseconds(errorLogToleranceInMilliseconds);

        return _existingErrorLogs.Any(x =>
            x.Name == logEvent.Name &&
            x.EventDateTime >= eventDateTimeFrom &&
            x.EventDateTime <= eventDateTimeTo);
    }
```

... it's a bit better.

Comment: I thought the general question would be too vague, so I decided to ask a question about a concrete case. If you find inconsistencies, feel free to edit the question.

Comment: I don't like `IsApproximately`, I would have to look at its implementation to find out what "approximately" actually is. What about something like `WithinRange(x, y)`?

Comment: What type is `_existingErrorLogs`?

Comment: @RobH It is defined as : private readonly IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.ErrorLog>  _existingErrorLogs;

Comment: @eurotrash I have done that. WithinRange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your current implementation, you write:

> The problem is that I think it is terrible.

But then, you don't explain why.

Then you go ahead and write much longer code, and a long list of objections.

In other words, maybe your original implementation is not so bad after all :)

The original code checks if there is any event that happened *within the same second* (more or less) as the reference event in the parameter (+ an additional date filter). The alternative implementation changes this logic to ±500 millis, which is different. Regardless of the logic you choose, the first option has some important benefits:

- Simple
- Efficient: sets constant values before a loop, rather than recalculate in every iteration

So I suggest to stick with that. Also remember [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: Well, I will try to explain, this is validation step that happens before a subset of logEvents are mapped to ErrorLog instances. The reason, why it is an approximate match, is that database date-time may be rounded up or down. It is terrible as I imagine .99999988 can be rounded up, truncate second drops milliseconds, and adds a second (that seems plain wrong). Even floats have 6 reliable decimal digits (0.005 s could be 0.0000005 s). The _existingErrorLogs is retrieved beforehand and quite frankly I do not see how code is any less efficient. But yes, the simplicity...

Comment: Maybe it would simpler if I sould use ToOADate, there are 86400 s in one day and thats and 0.005s is 5.787(037)... × 10^-8.

Comment: Whether it's within a second, or within ±interval, or something else, is an implementation detail. I think it's independent from the points I'm making here, and you can choose any logic you like.